# Word2vec Re-training with new corpus, how the weights will be updated for the existing vocabulary?

Tags: python, word2vec

Scenerio: A word2vec model is trained on corpus C1 with vocabulary V1. If we want to re-train the same model with another corpus C2 having vocabulary V2 using train() API, what will happen out of these two:

1. For model, weights for V1 intersection V2 will be reset and re-training for with corpus C2 will come up with all together new weights
2. For model, re-training with corpus C2 will be continued with the existing weights for vocabulary V1 intersection V2.

Which one is correct hypothesis out of the above two?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understand this option correctly, you are resetting all the weights of the shared words and then train them on the C2 data... This would mean that all the information on the shared words from C1 is lost, which would seem like a big loss to me. (I dont know the corpus sizes). Also, how different are the two corpora? How big is this intersection? Do the corpora cover similar topics/areas or not? This could also influence your decision on whether losing all the info from the C1 corpus is okay or not okay.
2. This seems like a more logical flow to me... but again the difference in corpora/vocabulary is important here. If a lot of words from C2 are left out because of the intersection, you can think of ways to add unknown words one way or another.

But in order to asses which option is truly 'best' in your case, create a case where you can measure how 'good' one approach is according to the other. In most cases this involves some similarity measure... but maybe your case is different..

Comment: I was not asking for the correct option, I was asking, if I am using train() API to retrain already trained model, which hypothesis will be correct?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how my answer is not providing information towards that question..?

Comment: Hey, you are elaborating the scenarios which I had mentioned, while I wanted to know the underlying principle behind train() API being provided. I understand there is not much gain or no gain if it is following scenario 1. 
To be more direct, I wanted to know which principle train() API is following out of the above mentioned two instead of elaboration on scenarios, which I am understanding already.

Answer (score 0):

Why not initiate each of the word2vec parameters with random generated numbers for each run? I could do this and with careful selection of the random numbers for each parameter (numFeatures, contextWindow, seed) I was able to get random similarity tuples which I wanted for my usecase. Simulating an ensemble architecture.

What do others think of it? Pls do reply.